# « Taper une vitesse » en voiture etc. ?

Tags: sens, expressions, registre-familier

> [**Taper**](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/taper), verbe
>  **I.** − Empl. trans. **B.** Taper qqc, **4.** Atteindre une certaine vitesse. *Nous « tapions » un gentil petit 90 (km/h)* (M. Grancher, *L'Envers de la course*, 1935ds Petiot 1982). *Ta Bugatti, on sait qu'elle tape
>   du 130* (R. Gignoux, *Le Prof d'anglais*, I, II ds Thomas1956).
>
> [Étymol. et Hist.](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/taper) I. B. 4. 1869 « exécuter médiocrement sur
>   un instrument de musique à clavier » taper une valse (Flaub., *Éduc.
>   sent.*, t. 2, p. 14 [1839 trans. indir. *le piano dont elle a tapé
>   exécrablement* (Barb. d'Aurev., *Memor*. 2, p. 396)]);
>
> [ *Trésor de la langue française informatisé*, TLFi - « *taper* » ]

Est-ce que je comprends bien qu'une automobile « *tape une vitesse* » comme on tape médiocrement une valse sur un piano; peut-on brièvement expliquer l'analogie, vu le son [différent](https://youtu.be/Wy_YjyAXmfA?list=PLB4305E29BD936BDF) ? Ou s'agit-il d'un autre instrument ? Entend-on généralement d'avoir « *tapé* une voiture »<sup>1</sup> le fait de lui avoir fait atteindre sa vitesse maximum ?  Est-ce que le bateau ou l'avion *tapent* aussi des vitesses ?

---

<sub>1. J'ai entendu une personne au Québec dire qu'elle avait « *tapé* (ˈteɪpe) *le char* », dans le sens d'avoir accéléré à toute allure jusqu'à la vitesse maximale le cas échéant. Vu la prononciation essentiellement identique au [mot anglais](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-cobuild-learners/tape), sauf pour la finale en é, je n'avais jamais fait le lien avec *taper une vitesse*... si lien il y a.</sub>

Comment: It probably goes without saying, but it’s interesting to me that the English “hit” has that same meaning, i.e., “reach/obtain” (atteindre/toucher) in similar (and even expanded?) contexts: “I/this car [can] hit 200 mph” (speed), “I just hit the big 6…0” (age), “We hit 120 F today, a new record high” (temperature/records), “We hit all the highlights/hot-spots” (points/places of interest), etc (there’s even “hitting bottom,” as perhaps I have with this comment!).  But I’m not sure if the “atteindre/toucher” sense of “taper” can be expanded beyond contexts involving speed.

Comment: Is it possible that the sense of “tapé le char” that you heard your friend say in Québec (which seems different than the “taper/atteindre une vitesse”) could come not from the past participle of the verb “taper,” but from a verb formed from the noun “tapis [de sol de voiture]” to correspond with (and actually be more accurate than) the English “floored”?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tous ces sens sont complètement différents:

#### 1. Synonyme argotique d'**aller**, d'**atteindre** ou d'**être capable d'atteindre**

*Nous « tapions » un gentil petit 90* signifie que nous conduisions à cette vitesse et que nous l'estimions telle une vitesse de croisière. 
*Ta Bugatti, on sait qu'elle tape du 130*, signifie que ce véhicule a la capacité d'atteindre cette vitesse.

Dans le cas de la vitesse, ce sens est à prendre comme un synonyme argotique du verbe *aller*. Il suffit de remplacer *taper un/du* par *aller à* dans les exemples ci-dessus pour s'en convaincre.

Cet usage n'implique aucune notion de médiocrité (au contraire).

On peut étendre ce sens à tous véhicules, et parfois aux humains et animaux.

> Il s'est tapé une petite bourre hier... 220Km/h, quand même ! (*bourre* est un synonyme argotique de *vitesse*, ici. Et il pourrait s'agir de n'importe quel véhicule.)
>
> Un bruit a effrayé mon chat tout à l'heure. Il a tapé une vitesse pour aller sous le lit!

On peut même généraliser plus avant. Ici, *taper* signifie toujours *atteindre*, ou encore *s'élever à*:

> Attention avec ce jet haute-pression, il tape du 100 bars ! Ne te blesse pas !
>
> La vapeur qui sort de ce tuyau tape dans les 300°C... un bon conseil, ne vous en approchez pas !

#### 2. Synonyme argotique de **dérober**, **voler** (dans le sens de *dérober*)

*Il m'a tapé ma voiture* signifie *Il m'a volé ma voiture*.

On peut l'employer de toutes les façons:

> On m'a tapé mon vélo ! Je suis furieux.
>
> Il a tapé une voiture. Il a roulé deux semaines avec avant de se faire attraper. Résultat, il est en prison maintenant.

#### 3. Il arrive que *taper* soit employé pour signifier de façon argotique **entrer en collision** (avec un véhicule)

> En prenant ma voiture sur le parking, tout à l'heure, j'ai vu qu'on a tapé mon aile droite. J'ai une rayure longue comme ça !

Attention, il y a un risque de confusion avec le sens **2.** !

#### 4. En musique, *taper* peut signifier **jouer maladroitement**, ou encore **en dilettante**. Mais aussi **jouer avec virtuosité**. Il s'agit là encore d'argot.

Exemple signifiant *en dilettante*:

> Je tape un peu de guitare, mais pas souvent. Que le week-end.

Exemple signifiant *virtuose*:

> Il y a eu un rappel, et là, il a tapé un solo de violoncelle... je ne trouve pas les mots.... magnifique !

#### 5. Ce dernier sens est à rapprocher du sens 1.: *atteindre*, *être capable d'atteindre*. Il tend d'ailleurs à se généraliser pour marquer de façon argotique l'appréciation:

> Comment trouves-tu ces chaussures ?
> Superbes. Elles tapent !

Ou encore:

> Il joue du tennis, mais à quel niveau ?
> Tu n'imagines même pas. Il tape! Premier de sa ligue après seulement deux ans !

Comment: Le verbe *taper* est en effet d'une extrême polysémie dans le langage courant / familier. Cette excellente réponse en donne déjà une idée, mais il y en a encore bien d'autres.

Comment: Oui, taper c'est un peu le verbe ultime. Limite schtroumfer :) Quant à "j'ai tapé la voiture", c'est avoir eu un accrochage, effectivement, car là le contexte ne me laisse pas penser que taper puisse signifier voler!

Comment: Pour moi aussi, c'est de l'argot. Je plussoie cette réponse :-)

Answer (score 3):

Je pense que taper fait ici référence à l'aiguille des vitesses qui approche la barre des 90 km/h.

Cette expression figurée veut dire qu'on tape une vitesse plutôt que de taper un objet.

> Un avion de chasse ça tape bien du 2000 km/h ! - Jean-Mi, PMU

Comment: "Jean-Mi, PMU" - Hahaha :) :) :)

Comment: +1 pour l'explication de l'aiguille qui est *au taquet*

Comment: @cl-r L'aiguille au taquet c'est quand elle se rend au bout du l'indicateur de la vitesse (elle pourrait même y disparaître) ou ce sont les lignes "graduées" apparaissant sous chaque nombre ?

Comment: Merci! J'ai bien peur de ne pas comprendre la référence à Jean-Mi, PMU... ça un lien avec les opérations en Irak de l'aviation de la République ? On parle du [Dassault-Rafale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dassault_Rafale) ?

Comment: @Amphiteóth C'est juste que le PMU est un style de bar caricaturé. On blague sur les discussions alcoolisés

Comment: @Amphiteóth on dit aussi "des conversation du café du commerce", PMU est plus facile à taper !

Answer (score 2):

On dit "**taper le {vitesse}**" ou bien "**taper du {vitesse}**". 
Exemple : Ma voiture tape le 220 à l'heure. C'est à dire la vitesse qu'elle peut atteindre et c'est valable pour tout moyen de transport (automobile, moto, etc)

Comment: Merci! Est-ce qu'on veut dire qu'on préfère utiliser "tape le" pour la vitesse maximum, alors que "tape du" c'est le temps présent et l'état temporaire (on pourrait taper davantage) ?

Comment: Je ne saurais confirmer ma réponse. Remarque : On pouvait même dire taper + vitesse directement sans "le" ou "du" pour dire qu'on a atteint une certaine vitesse "Nous « tapions » un gentil petit 90 (km/h)" comme le montre ce lien : http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/taper.

Answer (score 1):

Outre les différents sens répertoriés par Shlubu, il me paraît utile de signaler cet emploi également très courant  : **se taper**, avec deux sens différents (voire opposés), là encore argotiquement.

Sens "positif", généralement en relation avec la nourriture : **s'offrir** (un plaisir), ou **s'autoriser** (un excès).

> On s'est tapé un sacré gueuleton.
>   Je me suis tapé un énorme baba au rhum.
>   Elle s'est tapé tout le reste du plat !

Sens "négatif", ou pour le moins supposant un effort : **s'imposer** (un travail, une difficulté, par obligation ou par choix).

> Je me suis tapé le chemin à pieds.
>   Je me suis tapé le boulot tout seul.
>   J'ai préféré me taper le travail en retard avant d'aller me coucher.

Comment: Il me revient tardivement que j'ai oublié un exemple notoire de l'emploi positif de _se taper_, cette fois dans le domaine des relations sexuelles. Plus qu'argotique, c'est carrément vulgaire, mais malheureusement très courant : **Cette nuit je me suis tapé une super-nana !**

Comment: Plus tardivement encore, la lecture de [cet autre post](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/13766/comment-traduire-i-dont-give-a-damn) me conduit à réparer encore un oubli important : **je m'en tape** (= I don't care) est un autre emploi argotique de _taper_, avec une signification encore bien différente des précédentes.