# Comment traduire « I don't give a damn » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, registre-familier, vulgarité

Quelles possibilités existent pour traduire « I don't give a damn » ?

Comment: Related: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/7990/comment-d%c3%a9cortiquer-je-men-balance-je-men-bats-l%c5%93il-je-men-tamponne-le-c

Comment: "va voir ailleurs si j'y suis" is probably one of the most common and curious pseudo-equivalents known most natives.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Populaire :

> Je m’en bats l’œil.
>   Je m’en tamponne le coquillard.

Familier :

> J’en ai rien à fiche. / Je m'en fiche.
>   J’en ai rien à secouer.
>   Je m'en fous.

Vulgaires :

> J’en ai rien à foutre.
>   J’en ai rien à branler.

Très vulgaire :

> Je m’en bats les couilles.

On peut observer un thème sous-jacent à ces diverses propositions.

Si on préfère éviter le familier et le vulgaire, on se contentera d’un banal :

> Je m’en moque.

Comment: Il manque le poétique « Je m'en bats les couilles ».

Comment: Pourquoi ne pas l’avoir ajouté ?

Comment: C'est vrai, j'aurais pu mais j'ai tendance à me limiter aux corrections quand j'édite une réponse qui n'est pas de moi. Le « Très » vulgaire est peut-être excessif, cette expression très courante me semble du même registre que les deux précédentes.

Comment: « Je m'en moque. » correspondrait peut-être mieux à « _I don't care._ » Je pense que « _I don't give a damn._ » est un poil plus fort et pourrait être matérialisé dans ta traduction. Que penses-tu de « Je m'en moque éperdumment. » ? Le principal « problème » de cette proposition monte peut-être dans le registre de langage du fait de l'utilisation d'un adverbe qui pourrait sembler désuet.

Comment: Je me suis permis d'ajouter "J'en ai rien à cirer."

Comment: @Édouard *'Bourgeois'* : "Je n'en ai que faire." --- *Chiraquien* : "Cela m'en touche une sans faire bouger l'autre." http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/cela_m%E2%80%99en_touche_une_sans_faire_bouger_l%E2%80%99autre ; --- *'Aristocrate'* : "En quoi cela nous intéresse-t-il ?"

Answer (score 11):

La langue française ne manque pas d'expressions toutes plus ou moins colorées pour traduire « *I dont give a damn* ». De la plus neutre :

> Je m'en fiche.

...aux plus vulgaires :

> J'en ai rien à branler.
>   J'en ai rien à foutre.

Il y a aussi :

> Je m'en fiche comme de l'an 40.
>  J'en ai rien à cirer.

Tout dépend de l'intensité du sentiment.

Comment: *Je m'en fiche* est vraisemblablement le plus proche en terme de registre de langue, parfois contracté en *J'm'en fiche*. Curieusement, personne n'a proposé *Je m'en tape* qui est aussi assez courant.

Answer (score 7):

Here are three more that I hear on occasion ranging in order from more polite/formal to more colorful/familiar:

[Ça m’est égal.](http://french.about.com/od/vocabulary/a/ca-m-est-egal.htm)

[Je m’en balance.](http://dictionary.reverso.net/french-english/je%20m%27en%20balance)

[Je m’en fous [complètement]](http://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-anglais/Je%20m%27en%20fous).

(This last one even seems to have given rise to noun-forms describing [indifferent people](http://www.linternaute.com/dictionnaire/fr/definition/je-m-en-foutiste/) and their [indifferent attitudes/states of being](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/je-m_en-fichisme/44851).)

Comment: il manque juste "rien à cirer/j'en ai rien à cirer" aux listes, et pour les plus vieux (dépendamment de l'époque) "je m'en moque comme de l'an 40"

Comment: Et puis encore "je m'en tape", argotique mais sans trop...

Answer (score 6):

Au Québec, il y a plusieurs variantes des expressions françaises, et quelques-unes sans analogue direct :

1. « *Je n'en ai rien à fiche* » est dit ici « *Je m'en fiche* »
2. « *Je n'en ai rien à foutre* » devient « *Je m'en fous* »
3. et les autres traductions sont basées sur des [sacres](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sacre_qu%C3%A9b%C3%A9cois_%28juron%29), comme « *Je m'en câlisse* »; ou « *Je m'en sacre* », etc.

Comment: Les variantes 1 et 2 existent aussi en France (je les utilise plus volontiers, hormis dans le cas où je suis en colère et que je veux vraiment mettre l'accent sur mon désintérêt total de l'excuse ou de la justification qu'on m'avance).

Comment: @Chop je n'étais pas au courant! Je sais qu'au Québec je n'ai jamais entendu la version avec "je n'en ai rien à..." être utilisée sérieusement; je ne savais pas que la version plus courte était aussi utilisée en France.

Comment: @Amphiteóth C'est corrigé! Merci!

Comment: Au Québec, on dit aussi, "je m'en contrefous" et "je m'en contrecâlisse" et plus vulgairement, "votre idée [ne] vaut pas de la marde".

Answer (score 6):

Traduit par :

> c'est le cadet de mes soucis

dans « Autant en emporte le vent. »

Comment: Très surprenant que cette expression n'ait été mentionnée dans aucune des réponses existantes...

Answer (score 3):

Dans un registre soutenu et quelque peu suranné il y a : Peu me chaut ! Ou il m'en chaut...

Comment: Effectivement un peu désuet, mais j'adore l'utiliser pour cette raison.

Comment: Le verbe [_chaloir_](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/chaloir). Merci.

Answer (score 0):

Il y a aussi les expresssions « s'en soucier/foutre/battre comme de sa première chemise » ([Expressio](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/s-en-moquer-soucier-foutre-comme-de-sa-premiere-chemise.php)). Dans le sud de la France on peut aussi entendre la variante suivante ; lorsque « soucier » est utilisé l'expression est seulement familière, autrement elle est vulgaire.

- « s'en soucier/foutre/battre comme de ses premières chaussettes »

Les possibilités suivantes appartiennent à la langue correcte et proviennent du TLFi ;

- Se soucier de qqn/qqc. comme d'une guigne
- Se soucier de qqn/qqc. comme de sa première culotte

D'autres possibilités, de plus en plus  vulgaires

- n'en avoir rien à carrer
- n'en avoir rien à braire
- se batte le derrière ([ref](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/s-en-battre-l-oeil-s-en-tamponner-le-coquillard.php))
- se tamponner le sexe sur son siège ([ref](http://www.expressio.fr/expressions/s-en-battre-l-oeil-s-en-tamponner-le-coquillard.php))
- s'en taper le coquillard
- s'en tamponner
- n'en avoir rien à péter
- n'en avoir rien à chier
- n'en avoir rien à battre
- ça m’en touche une sans faire bouger l’autre

D'autres encore

- s'en foutre comme de sa première tétine
- s'en foutre comme de sa première chaussette
- s'en battre les tantifles

Comment: "i haven't got nothing to fart" adds cultural wealth to the foreign learner's lexicon.

Comment: i don't give a fart/shit also exists in english, and is fairly common, perhaps because of the art. i dont give a monkeys too.