# Je viens d'écouter dans une vidéo Youtube la phrase "Qui s'en bat totalement les couilles, ici?"

Tags: sens

Le contexte c'est une classe du lycée et je veux savoir quoi cela signifie. D'abord Je sait déjà que couille c'est vulgaire pour testicule.

Comment: Voir : https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/13766/comment-traduire-i-dont-give-a-damn/13768#13768

Comment: L'équivalent anglais "I don't give a damn" est moins vulgaire que "je m'en bats les couilles". 
Un équivalent aussi vulgaire serait "I don't give a fuck".

Comment: pas la réponse à ta question, mais dans ton titre il faut remplacer `écouter` (= to listen) par `entendre` (= to hear) ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other said, "*je m'en bats les couilles*" means "I don't give a damn". There are lots of synonyms, I'll use "*je m'en fous*" because I don't feel like writing *couilles* 10 times.

The whole sentence (with "*Qui ... ?*") comes, in my opinion, from the English phrase "Who cares ?", except in English the negation is the opposite as in French:

- "I **don't** care" is "*je m'en fous*" but
- "I care" is actually something like "*je **(ne)** m'en fous* ***pas***"

So my guess is that to keep the expression "catchy", the negation was swapped. Instead of asking "*Who cares?*" as "*Is there even one person who gives a damn?*", it's more natural to ask "*who else doesn't give a damn?*", which is basically what the sentence is.

I'm not 100% sure but when I started hearing this expression I immediately thought of "*who cares?*" because of the similarity, and the swap is actually pretty natural.

Comment: J'ai du mal à comprendre cette explication. Toutes ces expressions d'argot français auraient comme origine commune l'anglais *who cares* ??

Comment: @jlliagre "*Je m'en bats les couilles*" non, mais "***Qui*** *s'en bat les couilles ici?*", c'est possible. J'ai commencé à l'entendre très récemment, et ce serait pas la première expression anglaise "de jeune"  adaptée en français.

Comment: Passer de "je me xxx" vers "qui se xxx ?" est une transition standard en Français. Je vois mal comment l'anglais pourrait intervenir ici.

Comment: @jlliagre Peut-être que tu n'as pas les mêmes exemples que moi d'expression anglais adaptées, quand on connait pas l'original on dirait une "nouvelle" expression normale, mais quand on connaît l'original c'est flagrant. Peut-être que je fais une erreur en mettant celle de la question dans ce panier mais ça me paraît plutôt plausible.

Comment: Je comprends. Avoir un lien vers la video YouTube en question permettrait peut-être de se faire une meilleure idée de l'influence potentielle de l'anglais sur les paroles.

Answer (score 3):

"S'en battre les couilles" a le sens de "ne pas accorder d'importance à cela".
Il existe d'autres expressions familières:

> s'en ficher (familier)
>
> s'en foutre (vulgaire)

*S'en battre les couilles* est très vulgaire.

Answer (score 1):

L'expression *[s'en battre les couilles](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/s%E2%80%99en_battre_les_couilles)*, probablement liée à la plus ancienne *[s'en branler](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/s%E2%80%99en_branler)*, est apparue dans les années 1970 (ou plus tôt?), peut-être dans les quartiers nord de Marseille. Elle s'est ensuite répandue partout en France et signifie *s'en foutre*, *n'en avoir rien à cirer*, c'est à dire n'avoir aucun intérêt pour quelque chose.

Le dérivé « adouci » *balec* utilisé dans les expression *[j'm'en balec](http://www.dico2rue.com/dictionnaire/mot/33/s-en-balec)* ou *on s'en balec* est assez courant dans les cours de récréation.

Un autre dérivé poétique féminin est *je m'en [bat les steaks](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/s%E2%80%99en_battre_les_steaks)*...

Faute de lien vers la vidéo en question, je dirais que la question « **qui s'en bat totalement les couilles ici ?** » posée dans le contexte d'un lycée doit signifier :

> Quels sont les élèves de cette classe qui se désintéressent totalement de l'enseignement prodigué ici ?

La personne qui pose la question répondrait très probablement oui à cette question qui peut donc se réduire à :

> Qui pense comme moi ?

Comment: J'ai déjà entendu *je m'en bats les steaks* dans la bouche de locuteurs masculins, donc je me demande si l'expression est réellement un équivalent feminin. Ou peut-être le sens feminin s'est-il perdu ? J'avoue ne pas voir clairement quelle partie feminine du corps est associée aux *steaks*.

Comment: @Greg Il y a aussi des femmes qui disent "je m'en bats les couilles" et elles sont pourtant normalement constituées. C'est la force d'une expression tellement récurrente qu'on en oublie le sens. Quant aux steaks, c'est du même niveau poétique que moule...

Comment: @Greg Oui, bien sûr, cette expression est à l'origine le « pendant féminin » de la précédente. Voir le lien du wiktionary pour les détails physiologiques. *S'en battre les couilles* a mis du temps ne plus être exclusivement masculin (je me souviens d'ailleurs de la première fois où je l'ai entendu de la bouche d'une adolescente dans le RER B au début des années 2000), l'inverse a été beaucoup plus rapide.

Comment: ...du temps **à** ne plus être...

Comment: @jiliagre je n'ai jamais non plus considéré *s'en battre les steaks* comme spécifiquement féminin. A-t-on d'autres sources que la mention (d'ailleurs en "référence nécessaire") de wiktionary.org ?

Comment: @guillaume31 En voici une qui a onze ans contenant un post qui donne la même explication sur le sens de steak et un autre qui rapporte que l'expression a commencé par être exclusivement féminine (ce que je peux confirmer aussi) : https://fr.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20071001125321AAbDQtu